# ASP.NET Dynamic Data Image Field Template

Tags: sql-server, image-uploading, asp.net-dynamic-data

I'm engaged in a minor skirmish with Dynamic Data. I've got a custom database image field template to allow users to upload and edit images where **inserting** works but **updating** does not. I can make update work by removing the *if insert mode* around where the `uri` is set in the following code (in DBImage_Edit.ascx.cs):

```
protected override void ExtractValues(IOrderedDictionary dictionary)
{
  ...
  dictionary["contenttype"] = "image/" + imgext;
  dictionary["filecontents"] = new System.Data.Linq.Binary(FileUploadEdit.FileBytes);
  if (Mode == DataBoundControlMode.Insert)
  {
    dictionary["uri"] = imgname + "_" + DateTimeOffset.Now.Ticks.ToString() + "." + imgext;
  }
  ...
}
```

To recap, if the *uri* is set to something different than the previous value in the DB when **editing**, the  new image is uploaded successfully. If the *uri* is the same as the previous value in the DB, even though the *filecontents* and *contenttype* are changed, SQL Server never gets the news.

The metadata:

```
...
[DisplayName("Uri")]
[ScaffoldColumn(true)]
[Required]
public object uri { get; set; }

[DisplayName("Graphic")]
[ScaffoldColumn(true)]
[UIHint("DBImage")]
public object filecontents { get; set; }
...
```

I've also removed the *UpdateCheck* but that did not seem to change the behavior:

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_filecontents", DbType="VarBinary(MAX)")] //, UpdateCheck=UpdateCheck.Never
public System.Data.Linq.Binary filecontents
  {
    get
    {
...
```

(See commented out *UpdateCheck=UpdateCheck.Never* above)

Kind regards,

Jordan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I left it alone for a week, came back and figured it out easily.. sometimes you just need go for a walk, and not over-think these things.

The issue was caching. I changed the image handler url by adding a nocache param in the OnDataBinding:

**OLD:**

```
ImageEdit.ImageUrl = "http://localhost/WebServices.CAD/ImageHandler.ashx?uri=" + row.uri;
```

**NEW:**

```
ImageEdit.ImageUrl = "http://localhost/WebServices.CAD/ImageHandler.ashx?nocache=" + System.DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() + "&uri=" + row.uri;
```

Works as designed.